# Automapper different profiles for each project in .Net Core Solution

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a .Net Core 2.1 solution with the following structure

Infrastructure (automapper added here) << ApplicationCore (most of the logic services are here) << MVC

Infrastructure (automapper added here) << ApplicationCore (most of the logic services are here) <

(just to be clear the Infrastructure & ApplicationCore Class Library projects only exist once)

The ApplicationCore, MVC & Web API projects all have Classes/DTOs/View models specific to them. So having a single profile in the start up file of the MVC and/or API project could work, but would involve some duplication.

Also for testing I would like to run the ApplicationCore without the MVC or API projects.

Is there a good example project that shows how to have different profiles for each project?

Comment: “Infrastructure (automapper added here)”, but this project doesn't have DTO/View references, why do you add autumapper profile here?

Comment: So, you can have profiles wherever you may want. As long as you derive from Profile class, the AutoMapper package for .NetCore will sniff all the assemblies and add your profiles so that they are available through the IMapper injection

Comment: https://github.com/jbogard/ContosoUniversityCore

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu, I had seen that project, but it looks (to me) that automapper is being set up in the startup file of the web project. I want to also configure it in the ApplicationCore project so I can test it independently of the other web & API projects. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Jinish sounds great, is there some documentation on how this works? I've always used the Mapper.Initialize and passed in the profiles. In the class library project (Application Core) I have a profile, but cant workout how to make my class know it is there.

Comment: @Jimmy, Jimmy Bogard (Creator of AutoMapper) has some usage guidelines here: https://jimmybogard.com/automapper-usage-guidelines/. You can find tons of examples on the internet on its usage on Asp.Net Core though.

Comment: You can have the profiles wherever you want. But having `AddAutoMapper` in a library it's kind of problematic, as that's usually a concern of the whole app, a single instance of `IMapper` that can map anything. You can say you have a library AppCore that's in fact a helper for app code, not a module or anything like that. You can also have a library that has some private mapper that can only map internal types, distinct from the global mapper. Just make a decision that everybody understands and respects. Clarity and discipline are important for such things.

Answer (score 4):

I have same problem. Here is the solution in my way,

1. I created 'MapperProfiles ' in Application core library inheriting the 'Profile'

   ```
   public class MapperProfiles : Profile
   {
       public MapperProfiles()
       {
           CreateMap<YourModel, YourViewModel>();
           CreateMap<YourViewModel, YourModel>();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Added startup.cs to following line,

   ```
   services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MapperProfiles));
   ```
3. Now Controller modified as,

   ```
   private readonly IMapper _mapper;

   public YourController(ApplicationDbContext context, IMapper mapper)
   {
       _context = context;
       _mapper = mapper;
   }
   ```
4. now you can use mapper in controller ,

   ```
   YourModel model = _mapper.Map<YourModel >(YourViewModel);
   ```